# How to update the build settings on cocoapods 1.7.x

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm using `incremental_installation` and `generate_multiple_pod_projects` with `cocoapods 1.7.5`. I've got a couple of development pods and I would like to update the build active architecture only on all of them for a specific build configuration.

I did try something like this but it seems the API has changed and this is not a hash anymore.

```
installer.development_pod_targets.each do |development_pod_target|
        development_pod_target.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
```

I'm getting:

> undefined method `[]' for #<Pod::Target::BuildSettings::PodTargetSettings

Answer (score 0):

Acording with the [cocoapods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#install_bang), now you need to add this to the Podfile:

```
install! 'cocoapods',
         :share_schemes_for_development_pods => true
```

Follow the option description:

> Whether to share Xcode schemes for development pods.
>
> Schemes for development pods are created automatically but are not shared by default.
>
> this option defaults to false.

Comment: Even adding that to the top of my podfile does not solve the problem. What I'm trying to achieve is to change the 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' of a list of development pods for a certain build configuration.